# Displaying SQL results in different data tables

Tags: c#, html, sql, odbc

So I have written this method to fill a data table with a sql query. Ideally I want to learn how to have multiple queries displayed in their own tables on my page.

```
private DataTable GetOdbcData()
    {
         string connectionString = "dsn=sample;UID= user;PWD=password";
         using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
         {
             using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select * from sample"))
             {
                 using (OdbcDataAdapter oda = new OdbcDataAdapter())
                 {
                     cmd.Connection = conn;
                     conn.Open();
                     oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                     using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                     {
                         oda.Fill(dt);
                         return dt;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
      }
```

And I have this code to convert it to HTML to be displayed. I'm assuming the part I'll have to change is the method above.

```
if (!IsPostBack) // code to run at page load
        {
            // create a DataTable from our database
            DataTable dt = this.GetOdbcData();

            // to create an HTML string
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            // table start
            html.Append("<table class='table table-striped' margin-left='auto'>");

            // creates header row of table
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<th>");
                html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                html.Append("</th>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");

            // rows for data
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                html.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }

            // table end
            html.Append("</table>");

            // append the HTML string to name Table.
            Table.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
        }
```

I'm calling this to be shown by:

```
 <asp:PlaceHolder ID = "Table" runat="server" />
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: actually what is the problem.. if you can display a single DataTable bound to a DataGridView from a single Select statement.. then do the same thing with a query that returns multiple results and stored the dataset into a List<DataSet> from there you can get at the `DataSet.Tables[x]` meaning x is an integer starting at `0`

Comment: I want to know how to run more than one query at a time. Right now with my code I'd have to cut and paste it over again with a new query.

Comment: you do this by not hard coding the query but change it into a Stored Procedure and execute the results that way.. this is not that difficult ..

Answer (score 0):

Haha. Avoiding cut and paste is always the question. It's the only question!

Use [QueryFirst](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1108776/Your-SQL-wrapped-in-generated-code-Interesting-Ori). You specify your data source once, in app.config. You specify (connection, command, reader, fill) zero times! It's managed by QueryFirst. You create a new .sql file using the QueryFirst template (Add --> Visual C# Items). Each query gets its own file. Then call your query inside your foreach...

```
foreach(var item in GetAllSamples.Execute())
{
    //... do something.
}
```

Every line does something. You never repeat yourself. NO CUT AND PASTE :-)